# With dependency injection is my DB connection getting disposed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

I am wondering about how my context is being disposed, or if it is getting disposed at all!
I know I expext the garbage collecter to tidy everything up, but there is something just nagging the back of my mind.

I need to have the conext injected for unit testing

The Questsion, Is my code leaving DB connection open.

My service looks like this, with the context getting passed into the constructor, The dependancy injecting is handled by autofac.

```cs
public class FooService : IFooService 
{
    private readonly Context context;

    public CountryService(Context context)
    {
           this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll()
    {
        return context.Foo.ToList();
    }
}
```

My Autofac set up looks like this

```
public class ServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // "ThisAssembly" means "any types in the same assembly as the module"
        builder
          .RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
          .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
          .WithParameter("context", new MyContext())
          .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }
}
```

I Have seen on solution to add IDisposable

```
public class FooService : IFooService , IDisposable
{
    private readonly Context context;

    public CountryService(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll()
    {
        return context.Foo.ToList();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Did you read the docs?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Beware of mixing lifetimes of context and service. I suppose service is like a singleton, but the context should be not more than per request. You can also end up having multiple threads accessing the same context object which will result in connection state error.

In your code the context would be disposed when autofac container is disposed.

You should create some context factory or use the context directly in using block:

```cs
public class FooService : IFooService 
{
    public CountryService()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll()
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            return context.Foo.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill update my post to say, I need to have the conext injected for unit testing.

Comment: In your code you are using the same instance as parameter. You can register the context as a separate object `builder.RegisterType<Context>();` and you don't have to use the `WithParameter` definition.

Answer (score 0):

1) You shouldn't be disposing of your `Context` manually as it's injected (DI-ed), and technically it's not **owned** by your class's instance, i.e. Autofac manages its disposal as it could at the same time be injected into some other place, and it all depends on the lifetimes of all these objects (i.e. Autofac is the only one that actually knows when best to dispose of it).

2) Autofac has automatic disposal by using scopes, lifetimes. In your case that means your Container, root scope, and when that one goes out of scope all is going to be disposed. So no you shouldn't worry about it.
So, in short, Autofac sort of provides an alternative mechanism for managing the lifetimes of your objects, and the disposal. And it's actually very neat, and you can really be sure that things will get disposes in an organized manner.

With unit tests what I typically like to do, not necessary but gives me more control of things...

```
// within your unit test
using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    // and now resolve your services using the 'scope' (instead of the Container)
}
```

3) if you wish to have more control over lifetime of the DI-ed services and dispose of them yourself - you can use `Owned<>` e.g. `Owned<Context>` as your .ctor input parameter - and that means that it won't be automatically disposed and you can handle that in some custom manner that you see fit.